# How to call a scalar-valued from with a stored procedure

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

say I have a scalar-valued function with takes two Guids as parameters:

dbo.CarDistribution

The two Guids area ModelId and AreaId.

The function returns another Guid.

Could someone please explain to me how I call this function within a stored procedure and set the result returned to a variable.

I tried calling it with:

```
CarDistribution('a Guid in here', 'another Guid in here')
```

but I get the error
'Incorrect syntax near 'speciesareapresence_eval_internal''

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    declare @NewGUID uniqueidentifier    

    Select @NewGUID = dbo.CarDistribution (ModelId, AreaId)

    From dbo.YourTable
```